# Is a Florida corporation that shows no profit or losses required to file taxes?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, florida, federal-tax-law, corporate-tax-laws

A company is incorporated in the state of Florida; it was formed by a wantrepreneur. This company has no employees, no location, no profits, and no losses; the only proof this company exists is on paper.

Is this company required to file taxes for the previous year, and if they don't, will they face any punishment?

Comment: What does Company A have to do with Company B?

Comment: Do they have revenue/expenses?

Comment: @TTE please reread the part of the question "This company has no employees, no location, no profits and no losses; the only proof this company exists is on paper."

Comment: Yes I understand no profit no loss but you can have $4000 in revenue followed by $4000 in expenses which gives $0 profit/loss. I will assume those amounts are $0 also.

Comment: @TTE,  no money has gone through the business at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this company required to file taxes for the previous year, and if
>   they don't, will they face any punishment?

Yes. Every corporation is required to file an [IRS Form 1120](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1120) every year (the same rule does not apply to trusts or limited liability companies), even if it has no revenue or expenses. *See* [26 USC § 6012(a)(2)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/6012) and [Treas. Reg. § 1.6012-2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.6012-2) ("Except as provided in paragraphs (e) and (g)(1) of this section with respect to charitable and other organizations having unrelated business income and to certain foreign corporations, respectively, **every corporation**, as defined in [section 7701(a)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/7701), subject to taxation under subtitle A of the Code **shall make a return of income regardless of whether it has taxable income or regardless of the amount of its gross income.**").

The penalty, assuming that no tax is actually due as per the question, is a modest fail to file a return fine that was $210 in 2018. [26 USC § 6651(a) and (i);](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/6651) [Rev. Proc. 2018-18](https://www.irs.gov/irb/2018-10_IRB#RP-2018-18). The fine will be $215 in 2019 ($205 for an S-corporation). [Rev. Proc. 2018-57](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/rp-18-57.pdf).

A state income tax must be filed by a Florida corporation [only if it has income in the state](https://www.stateofflorida.com/taxes.aspx) in a given year. So, while there is a federal requirement and penalty, there is not a state one.

Comment: Not sure what the down vote was for (as the answer was correct), but I have added citations.